# Checking for correct number of ( [ and { in expressions?

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write a program for an assignment for my java class. The program is supposed to use Tokenization and the Stack class to check for correct balance of brackets, braces, and parenthesis in expressions.

What am i doing wrong?

My code

```
   import java.util.*;
   public class Lab10 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        input.close();      
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s, "[] () {}", true);
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokens.nextToken().trim();
            if (token.compareTo("(") == 0 || token.compareTo("{") == 0 ||
                 token.compareTo("[") == 0) {
                stack.push(token);
            }

            else if (token.compareTo(")") == 0 || token.compareTo("}") == 0        ||
                token.compareTo("]") == 0) {
            String popped = stack.pop();

            if (token.compareTo(")") == 0 && popped.compareTo("(") != 0 ||
                token.compareTo("}") == 0 && popped.compareTo("{") != 0 ||
                token.compareTo("]") == 0 && popped.compareTo("[") != 0) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }

    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error that you're facing?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is not checking that the stack is empty once the processing is done. Another thing wrong is not breaking from the loop once you find an error.

Comment: @nullpointer its not working, that is the problem.

Comment: @Eran Thank you! That makes since... I think that may fix my problem. Lets hope I can get it done within the next 30 mins, cause thats when it is due on line

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Eran , these could be some good changes to the code :

```
if(stack.empty()) {
    System.out.println("Error");
    break;
}
String popped = stack.pop();
if (token.compareTo(")") == 0 && popped.compareTo("(") != 0 || token.compareTo("}") == 0 && popped.compareTo("{") != 0 || token.compareTo("]") == 0 && popped.compareTo("[") != 0) {
    System.out.println("Error");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks guys. I was able to get it working, and get it turned in on time. I just had to add like three or four more lines of code, and it worked.